# How to calculate the time and space complexity of an N-gram model?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am using basic trigram (N=3) model with jaccard coefficient as similarity metric for document categorization. I need to calculate the time and space complexity of the algorithm. In general what is the complexity of an N-gram model?

Comment: there is no such thing as an N-gram algorithm... you should edit the question

Comment: are you referring to the language model extracted from ngrams? or are you referring to the complexity of ngram extraction?